# How do I view information contained in a file produced by `pdfsig -dump`?

Tags: pdf, certificates, signature, pdfsig

`pdfsig` shows some information about digital signature of a PDF document, and also allows to `-dump` it to file. How do I view all information from that file in accessible form? It contains much more information that `pdfsig` shows without `-dump` - various names and URLs. But it is a binary file, not text one and `/usr/bin/file` does not detect its format. It starts with bytes "30 80 06 09".

Can I somehow convert to to text file that shows all the information contained in binary file?

Answer (score 4):

The file can be inspected by the following command:

```
$ openssl pkcs7 -inform der -text  -print_certs -in  your_file.pdf.sig0
Certificate:
    Data:
        Version: 3 (0x2)
        Serial Number:
...
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

It does not verify any signatures, only dump information about them and about the certificate.

Comment: rara avis ... many thanks